# VBS file length loop

Tags: loops, vbscript

I have a script to list the files in a directory including their length:

```vb
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set txtOut = objFSO.CreateTextFile("d:\FileNameLength.csv")
FoldersRec "d:\MyData"

Sub FoldersRec(Startfolder)
  Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Startfolder)
  Set colSubfolders = objFolder.Subfolders

  For Each objSubfolder In colSubfolders
    FoldersRec(objSubfolder)
  Next

  For Each file In objFolder.Files
    strZeile = file & ";" & Len(file)
    txtOut.WriteLine strZeile 
  Next
  ''MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

It works fine. What I would like to change is to convert it to an explicit loop after which I can add something, like for instance a message box.

If I just enter `MsgBox "Done"` just before `End Sub` it would appear for each file.

Therefore, the idea is to add something like `loop while file exists` or `loop while Len(file)>0`. But I am not quite sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not like this:

```
Set txtOut = objFSO.CreateTextFile("d:\FileNameLength.csv")
FoldersRec "d:\MyData"
MsgBox "Done"
```

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

ListSizes fso.GetFolder("D:\MyData"), fso.CreateTextFile("d:\FileNameLength.csv")
MsgBox "Done"

Sub ListSizes(folder, outStream)
  Dim subfolder, file

  For Each subfolder In folder.Subfolders
    ListSizes subfolder, outStream
  Next
  For Each file In folder.Files
    outStream.WriteLine file & ";" & file.Size
  Next
End Sub
```

This way you can pass any Stream object to `ListSizes`, for example the console (when called through cscript.exe):

```
ListSizes fso.GetFolder("D:\MyData"), WScript.StdOut
```

Also, I suspect want the file `.Size` (in bytes), and not the length of the file path?

Comment: No, I wanted that length of the file path. That's why I called the output file FileNameLength.csv, but apart from that your solution is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I was just guessing. Note that you should add some error handling, because currently this will crash when it cannot access a folder.

Comment: Good point. I added `On error resume next` to the code below.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the best solution for my problem:

```vb
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

ListSizes fso.GetFolder("s:"), fso.CreateTextFile("r:\FileNameLength.csv")
MsgBox "Done"

Sub ListSizes(folder, outStream)
  Dim subfolder, file

  For Each subfolder In folder.Subfolders
   On Error Resume Next
   ListSizes subfolder, outStream
  Next

  For Each file In folder.Files
    outStream.WriteLine file & ";" & file.Size & ";" & len(file)
  Next      
End Sub
```

With this solution I get both file name length and file size.

Comment: FYI `On Error Resume Next` is function-scoped. When you enable it, it will be on for the rest of the function. You don't need to turn it on twice.

Comment: True, I removed the second one.

Comment: As a general tip, I would try to minimize the area of code that is affected by `On Error Resume Next`. Ideally, it's only in effect for a single statement. This way you can still see the *other* errors that your program produces, which makes debugging a *lot* easier.